# Can IntelliJ IDEA select "the current branch and its remote tracking branch"?

Tags: intellij-idea

When working on a branch together with colleagues, I find it useful to limit **IntelliJ IDEA's Git Log view** to the local branch I'm working on plus the remote tracking branch. This way, I see all the commits that are relevant to working on this branch.

Every time I switch branches and want to get that filter, I manually select HEAD and the remote branch. I found no way to tell IDEA to always select the current branch and its remote tracking branch.

Is there a way to let the Git Log view **select "the current branch's remote tracking branch"** once, and have it automatically pick the right remote branch when I checkout another local branch?

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4, but will likely update to 2020 soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can update to 2020 and check new Branches Dashboard under Log tab in Git tool window.

Then you can select local and remote branches and you will get log filtered.

Please see what's new in 2020 here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#version-control

Also please see and vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-233730